# How to get this form validation script working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a form and a form validation script that checks if all fields are filled in, the name and city fields contain only letters, the age and phone fields contain only numbers and if the entered email is a valid one. When used in the console, all of the statements work, but when I fill in every field, or fill in invalid values in the email field or phone number and age field, I still get an error message saying that the name and city field must contain only letters.

I have tried writing out every statement alone and also checking them one by one.

HTML & JS

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Age</label>
    <input type="age" class="form-control" id="inputAge" placeholder="Enter age">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputCity">City</label>
    <input type="city" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Enter city">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> -->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPhone">Phone number</label>
    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone number">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary erase">Erase</button>
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var name_cityRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    var age_phoneRegex = /^\d+$/;
    var nameValue = $('#inputName').val();
    var cityValue = $('#inputCity').val();
    var ageValue = $('#inputAge').val();
    var phoneValue = $('#inputPhone').val();
    var nameResult = name_cityRegex.test(nameValue);
    var cityResult = name_cityRegex.test(cityValue);
    var ageResult = age_phoneRegex.test(ageValue);
    var phoneResult = age_phoneRegex.test(phoneValue);
    var mailValue = $('#InputEmail1').val();
    var mailResult = emailRegex.test(mailValue);
    $(".btn.btn-primary.submit").click(function () {
        $('.form-control').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
            }
            else if (nameResult == false || cityResult == false) {
                $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please use letters only in the fields 'Name' and 'City'");
                $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                return false;
            }
            else if (ageResult == false || phoneResult == false) {
                $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please use digits only in the fields 'Age' and 'Phone number'");
                $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                return false;
            }
            else if (mailResult == false) {
                $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please enter a valid email adress");
                $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                return false
            }
            return true;
        })
});
</script>
```

When I leave all fields empty the warning is ok. But when I do anything else I only get the warning that I can only use letters in the fields Name and City.

All help is greatly appreciated for a beginner!

Comment: So... To make checking for email validation easier, use the JavaScript string.isEmail() function. Also, you're using invalid types for the input. I'd advice using text for name, phone number etc., and email for the email iput.

Comment: you code is not working, try to put it into snippet

Comment: @TimB There's no such a method in the String prototype.

Comment: I update code and posted answer check

Comment: Alright, must've got something wrong, then...

Comment: @TimB [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype), maybe you've a library adding the said method?

Comment: @Teemu possibly, though I do not remember installing such a library. Or maybe I'm getting senile at age 19 and using non-existent functions... :-O Either way, above advice is trash bin worthy (well, apart from the advice to use actual input types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are failing to reassign the variables outside of the onClick function. I have tested below code and it works for me, i admit it is probably not a perfect solution reassigning all the variables each time and perhaps you could place some in global scope such as the RegEx statements. I also removed the loop as i don't think you need to loop over everything 5 times to check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName">Age</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAge" placeholder="Enter age">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputCity">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Enter city">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhone">Phone number</label>
        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone number">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary erase">Erase</button>
</form>

<script>
        $(".btn.btn-primary.submit").click(function () {
            let name_cityRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            let emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
            let age_phoneRegex = /^\d+$/;
            let nameValue = $('#inputName').val();
            let cityValue = $('#inputCity').val();
            let ageValue = $('#inputAge').val();
            let phoneValue = $('#inputPhone').val();
            let nameResult = name_cityRegex.test(nameValue);
            let cityResult = name_cityRegex.test(cityValue);
            let ageResult = age_phoneRegex.test(ageValue);
            let phoneResult = age_phoneRegex.test(phoneValue);
            let mailValue = $('#InputEmail').val();
            let mailResult = emailRegex.test(mailValue);
                if (nameValue == '' || cityValue == '' || ageValue == '' || phoneValue == '' || mailValue == '') {
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                }
                else if (nameResult === false || cityResult === false) {
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please use letters only in the fields 'Name' and 'City'");
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (ageResult == false || phoneResult == false) {
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please use digits only in the fields 'Age' and 'Phone number'");
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (mailResult == false) {
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please enter a valid email adress");
                    $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                    return false
                }
                return true;
            // })
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is working! Only thing is that when I fill all the field with proper values, the error message of the email still appears

Comment: Glad it's working for you, make sure you have the correct ID on Email - i changed it when modifying as there was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why your tests gives you an error, but I think your `$('.form-control').each` is useless.

In this foreach you test all your fields for each field.

Maybe try without this foreach, just test all your fields when you click on the button by removing this bit of code :

```
$('.form-control').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
    }
})
```

I don't see any other problem.

Comment: This code is supposed to check whether or not all fields are filled in. If I remove it and send an empty form, I don't get an error that all fields must be filled...

Comment: Then you should only put the "empty test" in the foreach and not all the tests.

Comment: Tried it, and when I leave the form blank it gives me the only letters error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error I corrected that check below code.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var name_cityRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    var age_phoneRegex = /^\d+$/;
    var nameValue = $('#inputName').val();
    var cityValue = $('#inputCity').val();
    var ageValue = $('#inputAge').val();
    var phoneValue = $('#inputPhone').val();
    var nameResult = name_cityRegex.test(nameValue);
    var cityResult = name_cityRegex.test(cityValue);
    var ageResult = age_phoneRegex.test(ageValue);
    var phoneResult = age_phoneRegex.test(phoneValue);
    var mailValue = $('#InputEmail1').val();
    var mailResult = emailRegex.test(mailValue);
    
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
        }
        else if (nameResult == false || cityResult == false) {
            $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please use letters only in the fields 'Name' and 'City'");
            $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
            return false;
        }
        else if (ageResult == false || phoneResult == false) {
            $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please use digits only in the fields 'Age' and 'Phone number'");
            $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
            return false;
        }
        else if (mailResult == false) {
            $('.alert.alert-danger').text("Please enter a valid email adress");
            $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
            return false
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" id="inputAge" placeholder="Enter age">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputCity">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Enter city">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
   
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPhone">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone number">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit" onClick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary erase">Erase</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When I run this the error that says that not all fields are filled in appears from the start

Comment: check you input fields you have added 'type' instead of 'name' @LDR

Comment: you have used <input type="city" insead of <input name="city"

Comment: Adjusted it, still not working. Getting the error 'Please use letters only in the fields 'Name' and 'City''

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I will try some more